# Install ephem on linux

Tags: python-3.x, pyephem

Trying to install ephem on linux, python 3.4.3.

I'm trying pip install ephem and I keep getting the following error.

```
extensions/_libastro.c:3:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

I tried install libastro with the software manager but I still get the same error.  What do I have to do to install ephem.  Pyephem gives the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run this command :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

And pip install again